# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC00E000B): The Message Queuing service is not available

Tags: msmq

When MSMQManagementClass.Init(Object& Machine, Object& PathName, Object& FormatName) method is called it works fine when the client and msmq service are both on the same box.

When the client and msmq service are in **different domain** i get the following error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC00E000B): The Message
>   Queuing service is not available     at
>   MSMQ.MSMQManagementClass.Init(Object& Machine, Object& PathName,
>   Object& FormatName)

on windows 2008 server

Below code gives the error

```
var msmq = new MSMQManagement();
var machineName = MachineName
var pathName = null
var formatName = DIRECT=TCP:ipaddress\private$\testq
msmq.Init(ref machineName, ref pathName, ref formatName);
```

but

this works fine

```
var queue = new MessageQueue(FormatName:DIRECT=TCP:ipaddress\private$\testq)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean cross-domain or cross-forest?

[Cross-forest MSMQ? You need to be trusting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/06/27/cross-forest-msmq-you-need-to-be-trusting.aspx)

You are performing an RPC operation to a remote machine so the following should help:

[Understanding how MSMQ security blocks RPC traffic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx)

Cheers
John

Answer (score 0):

To use MSMQ it requires that MSMQ is installed on both the sender and receiver.

Comment: Sorry - just ran headlong into that one